# Использование time в Golang

Tags: golang

Есть простая задача.

На стандартный ввод подается строковое представление даты и времени в следующем формате:

1986-04-16T05:20:00+06:00

Ваша задача конвертировать эту строку в Time, а затем вывести в формате UnixDate:

Wed Apr 16 05:20:00 +0600 1986

Никак не могу понять, как реализовать это. Делаю так:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var s string
    fmt.Scan(&s)
    
    t, err := time.Parse("Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006", s)
    
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    fmt.Println(t.Format(time.UnixDate))  
}
```

То ли с шаблоном ошибка, то ли ещё с чем.
Прошу помочь разобраться.

```
panic: parsing time "1986-04-16T05:20:00+06:00" as "Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006": cannot parse "1986-04-16T05:20:00+06:00" as "Mon"
```

Answer (score 3):

Опечатка:

```golang
t, err := time.Parse("Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006", s)
```

Должно быть:

```golang
t, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, s)
```